# Deploy java "trusted.certs" by GPO to all users of domain

Tags: group-policy, java, deployment, certificate

In my domain, we have a couple of applications that establish a connection by java: when users do the Windows logon the box windows of Java appears and ask ""*Do you want to run this program?*" with the box which says "*Always trust content from this publisher*."

Often, users don't read it or just close this warning and after that the program won't work and they will call helpdesk because they can't work.

I would like to automatize this situation, avoiding the interaction with this windows. I have noticed that if I click "run" and "Always trust content from this publisher", the certifications are stored in **C:\users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security** and the file is "**trusted.certs**"

So, I thought to deploy this file by **GPO** to all users so they wont have to pay attention on the prompt.

If I am following the wrong road, please advice me without problem how to do it.

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

From the messages in your question, I assume the app is properly signed with a trusted certificate. If you want to avoid the regular Java security prompt, consider using [Deployment Rule Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deployment_rules.html). You can define rules based on the location of the app or its signing certificate.

When `ruleset.xml` is ready, package it into `DeploymentRuleSet.jar` and sign. Then deploy `DeploymentRuleSet.jar` into `C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment` on all your systems.